# Transaction block prevents the commit to happen in database how can we skip certain thing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using transaction block and doing some operation inside the block, there are certain things that should ignore transaction block, i can't move the update from the transaction block as it is tightly couple with code.

How can we skip certain portion and let the rest behaviour as usual

```
Record.transaction do
  check_for_errors required_columns
  create_report
end

def check_for_errors
 loop
  ...
 begin
  Methods
  // want to skip this perticular db update from transaction block
  job.update_column(total_number: loop index)
  // as this is under transaction block no changes can be seen on ui
 rescue => e
    populate_error_message(e.message)
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
 end
end
```

Any idea what can be done in this case?

Comment: What database do you use?

Answer (score 0):

To skip a particular db action within an existing transaction, you can execute it in a separate thread. E.g.for your case above

```
  ...
  Thread.new do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      job.update_column(total_number: loop_index)
    end
  end.join
  ... # continue method
```

Comment: Doesn't helped me ,